# _driver.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6detail12set_tss_dataEPKvPFvPFvPvES3_ES5_S3_b

Tags: python, linux, pycuda

I tried to run the Nvidia TensoRT's python samples, but got an error importing pycuda:

`ImportError: .../pycuda-2020.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/_driver.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6detail12set_tss_dataEPKvPFvPFvPvES3_ES5_S3_b`

My environment:

- **Nvidia Driver Version**: 460.73.01
- **CUDA Version**: 10.0
- **CUDNN Version**: 7.6.4
- **Operating System + Version**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **Python Version**: 3.6.13

How I installed pycuda:

- `pip install numpy==1.16`
- `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev -y`
- install boost:

  ```sh
  ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
  ./b2 --with-python include=".../include/python3.6m/"
  sudo ./b2 install
  ```
- install pycuda:
  I first run `./configure.py --cuda-root=/usr/local/cuda-10.0`, then I changed the settings in siteconf.py: `USE_SHIPPED_BOOST` --> `False`;  `BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME` --> `['boost_python36']`. Then

  ```sh
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

After installing PyCuda, I installed TensorFlow 1.15 and TensorRT 7. The error happened on the line `from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa`.

Please teach me how to address this problem. Thanks

Comment: You are missing boost::detail::set_tss_data.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by downloading the files in this [repo](https://github.com/inducer/bpl-subset/tree/3702fb119804dddde5eaf4a254822b891a947104), placing them into the pycuda folder. Then I set `USE_SHIPPED_BOOST = True` and wrapped it up.